# React redux with both promise and socket.io middleware

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, redux, react-redux

I am already applying "ReduxPromise" middleware,

```
applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);
```

I want to use also "redux-socket.io",

```
applyMiddleware(socketIoMiddleware)(createStore)
```

How do I combine them both?

Comment: Have you tried `applyMiddleware(socketIoMiddleware,ReduxPromise)(createStore)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doc [applyMiddleware](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html):

> **Arguments** *...middleware* (arguments): Functions that conform to the
>   Redux middleware API. Each middleware receives Store's dispatch and
>   getState functions as named arguments, and returns a function. That
>   function will be given the next middleware's dispatch method, and is
>   expected to return a function of action calling next(action) with a
>   potentially different argument, or at a different time, or maybe not
>   calling it at all. The last middleware in the chain will receive the
>   real store's dispatch method as the next parameter, thus ending the
>   chain. So, the middleware signature is ({ getState, dispatch }) =>
>   next => action.

Means that you can pass as many middlewares as you want. So the next line should work for you:
`applyMiddleware(socketIoMiddleware, ReduxPromise)(createStore‌​)`

Hope it makes sense